# Finding all possible iterations of a nested JSON structure

Tags: python, json

I have a config file that I've been working out of, Ex:

```
"Preprocessing": {
"BOW":{"ngram_range":[1,2], "max_features":[100, 200]},
"RemoveStopWords": {"Parameter1": ["..."]}
}
```

The idea is to take this data and run every iteration between the two preprocessing steps and pass it into a Preprocessing object. The output I'm looking for is:

```
[{"BOW":{"ngram_range":1, "max_features":100}, "RemoveStopWords":{"Parameter1": "..."},
{"BOW":{"ngram_range":2, "max_features":100}, "RemoveStopWords":{"Parameter1": "..."},
{"BOW":{"ngram_range":1, "max_features":200}, "RemoveStopWords":{"Parameter1": "..."},
{"BOW":{"ngram_range":2, "max_features":200}, "RemoveStopWords":{"Parameter1": "..."}]
```

Current code:

```
def unpack_preprocessing_steps(preprocessing: dict):
        """
        This script will take the Preprocessing section of the config file
        and produce a list of preprocessing combinations.
        """
        preprocessing_steps = [] # save for all steps bow, w2v, etc.
        preprocessing_params = [] # individual parameters for each preprocessing step
        for key, values in preprocessing.items():
            for key2, values2 in values.items():
                preprocessing_steps.append(key2)
                preprocessing_params.append(values2)
        iterables = product(*preprocessing_params) # Creates a matrix of every combination
        iterable_of_params = [i for i in iterables] 

        exploded_preprocessing_list = []
        for params in iterable_of_params:
            individual_objects = {} # store each object as an unpackable datatype
            for step, param in zip(preprocessing_steps, params):

                individual_objects[step] = param # This stores ever iteration as it's own set of preprocesses
            exploded_preprocessing_list.append(individual_objects)
        
        return exploded_preprocessing_list
```

Current output (and wrong) output is:

```
[{"ngram_range":1, "max_features":100, "Parameter1":"..."},
 {"ngram_range":2, "max_features":200, "Parameter1":"..."},
 {"ngram_range":1, "max_features":100, "Parameter1":"..."},
 {"ngram_range":2, "max_features":200, "Parameter1":"..."}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you - assuming you always want that same `RemoveStopWords` section. It generates the product of all feature keys and values:

```
from itertools import product
# pprint just to make output clearer
from pprint import pprint

config = {
    "Preprocessing": {
      "BOW": {"ngram_range":[1,2]},
      "RemoveStopWords": {"Parameter1": ["..."]},
    }
}

features, values = zip(*config["Preprocessing"]["BOW"].items())

bows = [dict(zip(features, v)) for v in product(*values)]

newconf = []
for bow in bows:
    newconf.append({
        "BOW": bow,
        "RemoveStopWords": config["Preprocessing"]["RemoveStopWords"],
    })

print(newconf)
```

Result:

```
[{'BOW': {'max_features': 100, 'ngram_range': 1}, 'RemoveStopWords': {'Parameter1': ['...']}},
 {'BOW': {'max_features': 200, 'ngram_range': 1}, 'RemoveStopWords': {'Parameter1': ['...']}},
 {'BOW': {'max_features': 100, 'ngram_range': 2}, 'RemoveStopWords': {'Parameter1': ['...']}},
 {'BOW': {'max_features': 200, 'ngram_range': 2}, 'RemoveStopWords': {'Parameter1': ['...']}}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to write this code with variable amounts of features and parameters. So the code should be robust enough to capture key values it's never seen before

Comment: Have updated the answer to generate all combinations of features - is this what you need?